# How to design/develop an integration layer or bus for different external services/apps

Tags: apache-camel, soa, mule, esb, spring-integration

We are currently looking into replacing one of our apps with possibly an ESB or some similar tool and was looking for some insights into how best to approach this.

We currently have a stand alone service that consumes/interact with different external services and data sources, some delivered through SOAP Web Services and others we just use a DB connection. This service is exposed through SOAP and we have other apps that consume this service but are very tightly coupled to it, now we also have other apps that need to consume some of the external services and would like to replace this all together with an ESB or some sort of SOA platform.

What would be the best way to replace this 'external' services integration layer with an ESB? We were thinking of having a 'global' contract/API in which all of the services we consume are exposed as one single contract where all the possible operations and data structures that we use are exposed under one single namespace, would this be the best way of approaching this? and if so are there any tools that could help us automate this process or do we basically have to handcraft this contract/API?. This would also mean that for any changes to the underlying services/API's we will have to update this new API as well.

If not then the other option I see is to basically use the 'ESB' as a 'proxy' layer in which all of our sources are exposed as they are, so we would end up with several different 'contracts' / API endpoints, but I don't really see the value in this.

Also given the above what would be the best tool for the job? is a full blown ESB an overkill or are we much better rolling our own using something like Apache Camel or Spring Integration?.

A few more details:

We are currently integrating over 5 different external services with more to come in the future.

Only a couple of apps consuming our current app at the moment but several other apps/systems in the future will need to consume some of these external services.

We are currently using a single method of communication (SOAP) between these services but some apps might use pub/sub messaging in the future, although SOAP will still be the main protocol used.

I am new to ESB integration so I apologize in advance if I'm misunderstanding a lot of these technologies and the problems they are meant to solve.

Any help/tips/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put in some design thoughts of what you want to achieve over time.

There are multiple benefits and potential pitfalls with an ESB introduction.

Here are some typical benefits/use cases

- When your applications are hard to change or have very different release cycles - then it's [convenient](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessagingAdapter.html) to have an ESB in the middle that can adopt the changes quickly. This is very much the case when your organization buys a lot of COTS products and cloud services that might come with an update the next day that breaks the current API.
- When you need to adapt data from one master data system to several other systems and they might not support the same interfaces, i.e. CRM system might want data imported via web services as soon as it's available, ERP want data through db/staging tables and production system wants data every weekend in a flat file delivered via FTP. To keep the master data system clean and easy to maintain, just implement one single integration service in the master data system, and adapt this interface to the various other applications within the ESB plattform instead.
- Aggregation or splitting of data from various sources to protect your sensitive systems might be a use case. Say that you have an old system that can take a small updates of information at a time and it's not worth to upgrade this system - then an integration solution that can do [aggreggation](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Aggregator.html) or [splitting](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Sequencer.html) or throttling can be a good solution.

Other benefits and use cases include the ability to track and [wire tap](http://www.eaipatterns.com/WireTap.html) every message passing between systems - which can even be used together with business intelligence tools to gather KPI:s.

A conceptual ESB can also introduce a [canonical message](http://www.eaipatterns.com/CanonicalDataModel.html) format that is used for all services that needs to communicate. If a lot of applications share the same data with several other applications (not only point to point) - then the benefits of a canonical message format can outweight the cost (which is/can be high). An ESB server **might** be [useful](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Normalizer.html) to deal with canonical data as it is usually very good at mapping from one format to another.

However, introducing an ESB without a plan what benefits you are trying to achieve is not really a good thing, since it introduces overhead - you need another server to keep alive, you need perhaps another team to understand all data flows. You need particular knowledge with your integration product. Finally, you need to be able to have some governance around it so that your ESB initiative does not drift away from the goals/benefits you have foreseen.

You should choose some technology that you are comfortable with - or think you can be comfortable with. Apache Camel is indeed very powerful and my favorite integration engine - [but it's not an ESB](http://camel.apache.org/is-camel-an-esb.html) as it does not come with a runtime that you can use to deploy/manage/monitor your integration services with. You can use it together with most Java EE application servers or even better - [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) (= [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/)+[Camel](http://camel.apache.org/)+[ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)+[CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)) which is built for this task.

The same goes with spring integration - you need to run it somewhere, app servers or what not.

There is a large set of different products, both open source and commercial that does these things.

Comment: I love camel+karaf. Simple lightweight ESB.